# Batch to delete all files in a folder with a wildcard in the path

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, delete-file

So what I'm trying to do is go into every folder in the following directory

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\"
```

and for every folder in it, regardless of the name, check if this path exists

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\Application Data\CSMRpt\"
```

if it exists then delete all txt files inside that director, if the path doesn't exists then do nothing and move on to the next folder inside "C:\Documents and Settings\"

This is what I came up with so far:

```
set PATH = "\Local Settings\Application Data\CSMRpt\"
set FILETYPE = "*.txt"
for /d %%g in ("C:\Documents and Settings\*") do if exist %%g%PATH% goto pathexists
:pathexists
del %%g%PATH%%FILETYPE%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set cwd=%CD%
set p=Local Settings\Application Data\CSMRpt
cd /d "c:\Documents and Settings\"
for /d %%I in (*) do (
    if exist "%%I\%p%\" (
        pushd "%%I\%p%\"
        del /q *.txt
        popd
    )
)
:: (change back to original directory)
cd /d "%cwd%"
```

Comment: You can have `cd` change drive as well with `cd /D fullpath`

Comment: Minor note: I tend to use `if exist "%%d\."`, with a trailing slash-dot, to check directory names.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things wrong here, you can't have spaces around the `=` in the set command, using `goto` wouldn't have passed the variable (you could however use call instead and pass it as a argument) you don't need quotes around every variable, `%PATH%` although you can reset it, you shouldn't for something like this as it is a environment variable.

Corrected code:

```
set THEPATH=\Local Settings\Application Data\CSMRpt\
set FILETYPE=*.txt
for /d %%g in ("C:\Documents and Settings\*") do if exist "%%g%THEPATH%." del "%%g%THEPATH%%FILETYPE%"
```

If you *really* didn't want the `for` loop to be one line you could do this as well

```
set THEPATH=\Local Settings\Application Data\CSMRpt\
set FILETYPE=*.txt
for /d %%g in ("C:\Documents and Settings\*") do if exist "%%g%THEPATH%." call :deltxtfiles "%%~g"

exit /B

:deltxtfiles
del "%~1%THEPATH%%FILETYPE%"
goto:eof
```