# How to specify multiple wildcards in a folder directory in CMD

Tags: batch-file, directory, wildcard

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028358/batch-to-delete-all-files-in-a-folder-with-a-wildcard-in-the-path) in regards to wildcards in directories. However, my problem is that I have multiple varying directory names between my static directories. For example:

O:\123456 Client Name\Spring\Shoot 1 12345\01 MHP 01\PlCache\GreenScreen\
O:\121212 Someone Else\Spring\Shoot 1 21212\01 MHP 02\PlCache\GreenScreen\

The above link only allows for one wildcard directory instead of muliples.

Within these GreenScreen folders, I have .png files I wish to delete. How would I write a .bat file that deletes *.png within O:\ *\GreenScreen\ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=U:"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.png" '
 ) DO (
 SET "targetpath=%%~pa"
 IF "!targetpath:~-13!"=="\GreenScreen\" ECHO DEL "%%a"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

I've changed to starting directory to `U:` to suit my system.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! I couldn't figure it out myself to save my life

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler option - it also echos the del commands to the screen until you remove the `echo` keyword.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "o:\" %%a in (GreenScreen*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="GreenScreen" echo del "%%a\*.png"
```